# Displaying UCI commands between a chess engine and Winboard/xboard

Tags: chess, uci

Is it possible to display the UCI commands being sent between a chess engine and Winboard/xboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UCI chess engine doesn't run directly in Winboard/XBoard. You have to use an 'interpreter' progream like Polyglot. If you want to know how a chess GUI communicates with an UCI engines use Arena and press F4. If you want to use another GUI you may take a look to UCIPlug.exe.

Google 'polyglot' or 'uciplug' to find out more..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nochetoengi](https://nocheto.sallyx.org/doc/nocheng/options/) with --log-file option to store all communication between this uci engine and any chess UI.